# Influence of pH on rennet coagulation of milk

Tags: enzymes, ph

I was looking for the reason why rennin works most efficiently at pH 6.7 (closer to a neutral environment than acidic).

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. Please take the time to finish reading the [Tour], and the Help on asking questions. It would help us to help you if you provided some context to your question. Are you interested in the pH in relation to the mechanism of action of the enzyme or to its biological environment? Tell us why you might expect it to have an acidic pH optimum. This might be obvious to you, but not necessarily to us. And what attempts have you made to answer this question yourself from freely available resources like Wikipedia?

Comment: Can you quote a source for rennin working more efficiently at pH 6.7?  As I understood things, chymosin ([rennin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chymosin)) has a pH optimum of about 3.8 (see for example [Protein engineering of chymosin; modification of the optimum pH of enzyme catalysis](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/2217134/)), as you would expect for a stomach enzyme.